# Selenium IDE, Selenium Client, Ruby, Rails 3, session maintenance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, selenium, client, webdriver

I am quite new to Selenium. Currently i am using selenium driver for writing test cases in ruby on rails. In the application, I am required to login and Logout for each test cases. So, I exported each test cases from Selenium IDE to rails 3. I am required to use same browser session for multiple test cases. So I am calling Login test before required test case to be executed in a single ruby file. Is it possible to maintain browser session for consecutive next tests in rails 3 either with Selenium Client or Selenium Webdriver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this issue for Selenium Client/Webdriver in Ruby on Rails 3. To maintain a session from test script to another script, the only thing you need is session variable. Since I have written different Login script and this script is being called in different other script files, so from this another file I have to access the session variable from Login script.
To access variable from Login script, the code inside is being converted to module.
This is how it worked for me:
----Start-----
------Login.rb-----
module ModuleName
def methodName
----Write particular Login code required through selenium---#

@variable = SELENIUM::CLIENT:DRIVER.new \ #---Create browser instance and store in a variable ---#

return @variable #--Return back the variable from this method
end

end

------File1.rb-----
require Login.rb #---Specify with path---#
include ModuleName

Class File < TestCase #--Extending resp. Test Class

def setup

@local = ModuleName.methodName #--Access Module's method that will return session object.
end
def test_file

--Access this @local in rest of the code--#
end

end
-----End----

This was the tweak to access variable from file1 to file2.
I hope this may help somebody.........